# simplexml_load_file - foreach shows one time loop

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have a table structure like this, I need to swing her foreach loop to extract all 848 elements. The problem is that the loop displays only one item instead of the actual amount sitting there. With the way with regular forem and idid substitution works, although writing the same thing is in my opinion longer and uglier.

Array structure:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [language] => pol
            [currency] => PLN
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                        )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object

                [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                        )       

            [etc...]
        )
```

I try this way

```
$chairXML = simplexml_load_file('toparser.xml');

        foreach ($chairXML->children() as $children) {

            echo $children->product['id'];

        }
```

But this doesn't work, loop return one record.

Comment: It would be easier to fix if you include a copy (or part of) your XML file rather than the object structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = ' 
<xml>
 <product>
   <cherry>1</cherry>
   <apple>3</apple>
   <orange>4</orange>
 </product>
</xml>';
$simpleXmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($simpleXmlObj->product->children() as $children) {
    print_r($children);
}
```

result

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 1
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 3
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 4
)
```

I think your problem in $simpleXmlObj->children() 
Try $simpleXmlObj->product->children()